# qtip - add a few links into the tool tip itself?

Tags: fullcalendar, qtip2

I'm using fullCalendar and have it so that when an events is clicked the qTip is generated (showing a bunch of details about that element). I want to have a few links within the qTip that are based on the element being clicked (thus, dynamic links). The links will provide a way to edit the underlying database record which the fullCalendar event is based on. I'd like to have some call back way of handling this.

Here's how I build my qTip in fullCalendar:

```
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
          content: {
            text: "Loading WO info...",
            ajax: {
              url: "/schedule/get-wo-details/",
              type: 'GET',
              data: { woID: event.woID },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data, status) {
                var content = "<table class='qtip-table'>"
                content += "<table>...add content here...";
                content += "<center>";
                // Here are my links...
                content += "<a href='#'>Unschedule</a> | ";
                content += "<a id='qtip-link' href='#'>Edit Note</a>";
                content += "</center>";
                this.set('content.text', content);
              }
            }
          },
          show: {
            event: 'click',
          },
          hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 1000
          },
          position: {
            viewport: $("#calendar"),
            effect: false,
            at: "left-center",
            my: "right-center"
          }
        });
```

I'm wondering if I can do something like:

```
$("#qtip-link").click(function(){
    // Do some ajax magic here...
});
```

This, so I've found out, doesn't work. How might I go about achieving this? It seems like a simple thing to do but can't seem to put together a decent Google search query to find the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. In my `eventRender` method where I create the `qTip` itself, I have the following code:

```
var e = event.woID;
content += "<a href='#' onclick=unscheduleEvent('" + e + "')>Unschedule</a> | ";
```

That simply creates a variable equal to some data I stored in the `event` when I generate the calendar. The `content` is the `HTML` to go into the `qTip` - so I add a link using my variable to pass to the `onClick` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the click event handler in eventAfterRender, or using jQuery's on or live handler to add handlers to dynamically created links

Answer (score 0):

You can bind double click on rendered event:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
        content: event.description,
    });
    element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        //put there some code for
    });
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. Why would I make a double click event? I want to have a couple of links in the qTip window that are dynamically based on the event that was clicked. Sorry, I think I may be missing something with your answer.